# Hand Posture Recognition Using SURF with Adaptive Boosting

Tags: image-processing, pattern-matching, gesture-recognition, surf, adaboost

I´m trying to implement an algorithm of this paper:

http://www.bmva.org/bmvc/2012/WS/paper5.pdf

It´s the "Training process for all target postures" algorithm, in the page 6.

Basicly is a technique that use adaboost and SURF (extractor of features) for hand posture recognition. Like I wrote before, i´m trying implement but i still didn´t understand this algorithm. The problem are some question that i have, like:

1. What is the matching score list, mention in page 5, last paragraph?
2. What is the relationship between threshold and the training process (trainning algorithm)?
3. In the line 7 of training algorithm: Which is the return of the function ht(Ix,ft,tet)?

I would like to know if someone have this algorithm implemented or if someone can help  me in this questions.

Thank you very much for the answer (help), because i´m already investing some time in this algorithm and i still didn´t understand this algorithm to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Scanning through the paper, here is what I inferred. Please note that I did NOT go through the paper in detail so I might be wrong, but having implement AdaBoost before, I can clarify your doubts:

1. During the testing part, you assign a matching 'score' to each posture in your database. You want to determine the posture of the test image as accurately as possible. The 'score' represents how 'close' the test posture is to the posture in the database. The posture with the highest score in the end is your result of matching/testing.

2 and 3. During selecting weak classifiers, you have a threshold so the iteration for selecting weak classifiers stops as soon as their weight becomes less than the threshold. The threshold should be optimum in that the 'selected' weak classifier should be unique enough to be able to classify its corresponding vector efficiently. At the same time, you should not be too strict on the threshold or the time taken for iterations will be very large. Hence, the threshold should be optimum, and the paper shows how to calculate it. This answers your second question. The function ht your talking about is the weak classifier.